# WSO2IS 5.3.0 - identity claims caching

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I believe I am seeing some caching of the identity claims in my application, which is using WSO2IS 5.3.0 . When an identity claim is changed via UserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues (for example, http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled ) , it takes some time for that change to be reflected in subsequent calls to UserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues

I've searched for the configuration mentioned here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Cache+Layers but don't see that in our setup. I'm also not seeing any other configuration that I could attribute to this behavior.

Looking for an explanation, thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is some caching. As far I know if you change the user claims / attributes through the userstore, the cache should be invalidated (as far I remember),

Comment: Could you point me to the relevant code/config? Having a hard time finding it

Comment: I found what I was looking for (the underlying issue was in our application itself).

For others' reference, the identity claims are managed by the configured IdentityUserStore, which can be found by this line in conf/identity/identity-mgt.properties

Identity.Mgt.User.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying this out from my comment

For others' reference, the identity claims are managed by the configured IdentityUserStore, the configuration of which can be found by this line in conf/identity/identity-mgt.properties Identity.Mgt.User.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore

(JDBCIdentityDataStore does do some amount of caching to prevent unnecessary DB hits, and does invalidate that cache upon writing)

Comment: Adding a clarification on identity claims to avoid confusion with other claims. Their claim URI starts with `http://wso2.org/claims/identity/`. WSO2 IS does not cache other claims.